# Java parallel streams: there's a way to navigate a binary tree?

Tags: java, concurrency, binary-tree, java-stream

I'm struggling to find a proper way to get a speedup from this stream:

```
    StreamSupport.stream(new BinaryTreeSpliterator(root), true)
                .parallel()
                .map(node -> processor.onerousFunction(node.getValue()))
                .mapToInt(i -> i.intValue())
                .sum()
```

`onerousFunction()` is just a function that makes the thread work for a bit and returns the int value of the node.

No matter how many cpus i use, the execution time always remains the same.
I think the problem stands in the Spliterator i wrote:

```
    public class BinaryTreeSpliterator extends AbstractSpliterator<Node> {

        private LinkedBlockingQueue<Node> nodes = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        public BinaryTreeSpliterator(Node root) {
            super(Long.MAX_VALUE, NONNULL | IMMUTABLE);
            this.nodes.add(root);
        }

        @Override
         public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Node> action) {
            Node current = this.nodes.poll();
            if(current != null) {
                action.accept(current);
                if(current.getLeft() != null) 
                    this.nodes.offer(current.getLeft());
                if(current.getRight() != null)
                    this.nodes.offer(current.getRight());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

But i really can't find a good solution.

Comment: How many nodes does your tree have? The minimum batch size of `trySplit` in `AbstractSpliterator` seems to be 1024. Maybe you should try to override `trySplit` to work better for trees.

Comment: The tree has 2047 nodes. I tried implementig my own `trySplit()` but i don't find the right way to split the tree, i get almost the same performances.

Comment: Have you ever tried: `com.google.common.graph.Traverser` in Google Guava?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To process data in parallel, you need a `trySplit` implementation to return partial data as a new `Spliterator` instance. The spliterator instances are traversed by a single thread each. So you don’t need a thread safe collection within your spliterator, by the way. But your problem is that you are inheriting the `trySplit` implementation from `AbstractSpliterator` which does attempt to provide some parallel support despite not knowing anything about your data.

It does so, by requesting some items sequentially, buffering them into an array and returning a new array based spliterator. Unfortunately, it does not handle “unknown size” very well (the same applies to the parallel stream implementation in general). It will buffer 1024 elements by default, buffering even more the next time, if there are as much elements. Even worse, the stream implementation will not use the array based spliterator’s good splitting capabilities, because it treats “unknown size” like the literal `Long.MAX_VALUE`, concluding that your spliterator has much more elements than the 1024 elements in the array, hence, will not even try to split the array based spliterator.

Your spliterator can implement a much more suitable `trySplit` method:

```
public class BinaryTreeSpliterator extends AbstractSpliterator<Node> {
    /**
     * a node that has not been traversed, but its children are only
     * traversed if contained in this.pending
     * (otherwise a different spliterator might be responsible)
     */
    private Node pendingNode;
    /** pending nodes needing full traversal */
    private ArrayDeque<Node> pending = new ArrayDeque<>();

    public BinaryTreeSpliterator(Node root) {
        super(Long.MAX_VALUE, NONNULL | IMMUTABLE);
        push(root);
    }

    private BinaryTreeSpliterator(Node pending, Node next) {
        super(Long.MAX_VALUE, NONNULL | IMMUTABLE);
        pendingNode = pending;
        if(next!=null) this.pending.offer(next);
    }
    private void push(Node n) {
        if(pendingNode == null) {
            pendingNode = n;
            if(n != null) {
                if(n.getRight()!=null) pending.offerFirst(n.getRight());
                if(n.getLeft() !=null) pending.offerFirst(n.getLeft());
            }
        }
        else pending.offerFirst(n);
    }

    @Override
     public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Node> action) {
        Node current = pendingNode;
        if(current == null) {
            current = pending.poll();
            if(current == null) return false;
            push(current.getRight());
            push(current.getLeft());
        }
        else pendingNode = null;
        action.accept(current);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super Node> action) {
        Node current = pendingNode;
        if(current != null) {
            pendingNode = null;
            action.accept(current);
        }
        for(;;) {
            current = pending.poll();
            if(current == null) break;
            traverseLocal(action, current);
        }
    }
    private void traverseLocal(Consumer<? super Node> action, Node current) {
        do {
            action.accept(current);
            Node child = current.getLeft();
            if(child!=null) traverseLocal(action, child);
            current = current.getRight();
        } while(current != null);
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<Node> trySplit() {
        Node next = pending.poll();
        if(next == null) return null;
        if(pending.isEmpty()) {
            pending.offer(next);
            next = null;
        }
        if(pendingNode==null) return next==null? null: new BinaryTreeSpliterator(next);
        Spliterator<Node> s = new BinaryTreeSpliterator(pendingNode, next);
        pendingNode = null;
        return s;
    }
}
```

Note that this spliterator would also qualify as `ORDERED` spliterator, maintaining a top-left-right order. An entirely unordered spliterator could be implemented slightly simpler.

You may implement a more efficient `forEachRemaining` method than the inherited default, e.g.

```
@Override
public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super Node> action) {
    Node current = pendingNode;
    if(current != null) {
        pendingNode = null;
        action.accept(current);
    }
    for(;;) {
        current = pending.poll();
        if(current == null) break;
        traverseLocal(action, current);
    }
}
private void traverseLocal(Consumer<? super Node> action, Node current) {
    do {
        action.accept(current);
        Node child = current.getLeft();
        if(child!=null) traverseLocal(action, child);
        current = current.getRight();
    } while(current != null);
}
```

but this method might cause stackoverflow errors, if your application has to deal with unbalanced trees (specifically, very long left paths in this example).

Comment: Thanks man, it works slightly better than before. Weirdly, the execution get worse if i increase the number of threads involved. I really need to understand better how those parallel streams works

Comment: Keep in mind that you need a significant CPU load to get a benefit. If there’s a way to estimate the number of nodes, providing an estimate size may improve the performance too.

Comment: I'm benchmarking with a complete tree with height of 10. I've implemented the same solution with both ForkJoin and ExecutorService and everything scales well, only streams are making me mad.